# How do I handle CFSocketCallBackType.dataCallback in Swift?

Tags: swift, sockets, unsafe-pointers, cfsocket

[All documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfsocketcallbacktype/1542295-datacallback) [and examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570163/getting-several-data-at-a-time-by-udp) say that if a socket's [`CFSocketCallBack`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfsocketcallback) callout is given a `.dataCallback` as its second parameter (`callbackType`), that implies that the fourth one (`data`) can be cast to a `CFData` object containing all the data pre-read from the socket.

However, when I try to do this, it fails:

```swift
private func myCallout(socket: CFSocket?,
                       callBackType: CFSocketCallBackType,
                       address: CFData?,
                       callBackTypeMetaData: UnsafeRawPointer?,
                       info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Void {

    // Behavior inferred from Developer
    // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfsocketcallback

    guard
        let info = info,
        let socket = socket
        else {
        return assertionFailure("Socket may have gone out of scope before response")
    }

    // <REDACTED>


    if callBackType == .dataCallBack {
        guard let data = callBackTypeMetaData?.load(as: CFData.self) else {
            return assertionFailure("Data Callback's metadata was not a CFData object")
        }

        foo(data as Data) // Crashes here
    }

    // <REDACTED>
}
```

The crash I get is this:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0).
```

In the debugger, when I type this:

```
(lldb) po callBackTypeMetaData!.load(as: CFData.self)
```

it just prints a pointer address (rather high, also; only two significant `0`s). However, when I type this:

```
(lldb) po callBackTypeMetaData!.load(as: CFData.self) as Data
```

It prints this:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

So it seems what I got is not really a `CFData`, but it's close enough to seem similar to it on the surface, until something actually tries to read it as such.

**So what's going on here, where is my data, and how do I fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = callBackTypeMetaData!.load(as: CFData.self)
```

reads a `CFData` pointer from the memory location that `callBackTypeMetaData!` points to. What you want is to "reinterpret"
the raw pointer as a `CFData` (or `NSData`) pointer:

```
if callBackType == .dataCallBack {
    if let rawPointer = callBackTypeMetaData  {
        let data = Unmanaged<NSData>.fromOpaque(rawPointer).takeUnretainedValue() as Data
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That definitely eliminated the crash! But I don't quite understand why... I thought that "Treating memory at a pointer's address as some type" was the same as "reinterpreting a raw pointer as some type". How are these two approaches different, and how can I know this difference in the future?

Comment: Also concerningly, when I print out `data` in the debugger, it says the byte count is `0` and the pointer is `0x000000000000bad0` on every run

Comment: @BenLeggiero: Your code loads `data` from the memory location that `callBackTypeMetaData!` points to. My code just assigns `data` to the value of `callBackTypeMetaData!`, the rest is type casting for the compiler. The documentation says that the raw pointer "is a" CFData object, not that it "points to" a CFData object.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's another reference vs. value thing

Comment: I ran into this always being an empty Data object and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong... :/

Comment: @BenLeggiero: Do you by any chance have a minimal sample project that you can share? Then I would look into it.

Comment: Anticipating this, I rewrote the whole project as a "SSCCE" over the weekend. It's a bit dirty and such, but it serves the purpose of replicating the important parts of the setup: https://github.com/BenLeggiero/Socket-IPC-SSCCE-2017-12-15

Comment: @BenLeggiero: It works in my test. Here is a minimal command-line socket client  which I ran against "netcat" as the server: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0a817aab1bd8fc00a9cd87601aa70c94. – In your project there is no registration for `.dataCallBack` at all, so that case wouldn't be hit anyway.

Comment: Whoops! I'd committed it in the middle of some test changes. I've updated it to add data callbacks when creating the sockets: [Client](https://github.com/BenLeggiero/Socket-IPC-SSCCE-2017-12-15/blob/master/Socket%20IPC%20SSCCE%202017-12-15/SSCCE%20for%20SO.swift#L28) | [Server](https://github.com/BenLeggiero/Socket-IPC-SSCCE-2017-12-15/blob/master/Socket%20IPC%20SSCCE%202017-12-15/SSCCE%20for%20SO.swift#L142) | [Diff](https://github.com/BenLeggiero/Socket-IPC-SSCCE-2017-12-15/commit/091bcc4437197ec3b19e410453aeb39e41fab929)

Comment: @BenLeggiero: Did you try my test program? It demonstrates that the answer is correct.